# SVNAdmin Create Repository URL not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I logged in via ssh and executed the following commands:

```
-bash-3.00$ svnadmin create /code/svn/Projects/myproject
-bash-3.00$ chmod -R g+w /code/svn/Projects/myproject
-bash-3.00$ chown -R :eng /code/svn/Projects/myproject
```

However I cannot connect to the repository url:

```
 svn+ssh://hostname.com/code/svn/Projects/myproject
```

I can connect perfectly fine to all the other repositories under Projects.

I also did mkdir trunk and put a dummy file under trunk.

Am I missing some step to make this repository accessible?

```
   org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The system cannot find the file
  specified.

   svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://thehost.com/code/svn/Proj  ects/myproject'

  svn: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: I suspect file that svn is struggling to find is not the file that you are looking for but a copy of an ssh executable so that it can create an ssh tunnel.. Ensure that you have installed ssh on the repo server. Ensure it is svn is configured to point to it.

Comment: Well I have several repositories under projects which are all working ...  I was just adding a new one as described above when I got this error.

Comment: Are the spaces in `'svn+ssh://thehost.com/code/svn/Proj  ects/myproject'` intentional or by accident?